# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException at Main.main

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Invalid input flow is not working- everytime i give a negative month value it gives me back this exception.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of months :");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        if(month<0)
        {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int a[] = new int[month];
        System.out.println("Enter the profit of each month in shipment");
        for (int i=0; i<month; i++)
        {
            a[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum = sum+a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Total profit : "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you look at your code flow you can see that your actual message should be "Invalid input, but I'm processing it anyways".

Comment: Think about the block with `if(month<0)`. Does this really do what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use `else` statement with `if` statement.

```
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of months :");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    if(month<0)
    {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }else{
    int sum = 0;
    int a[] = new int[month];
    System.out.println("Enter the profit of each month in shipment");
    for (int i=0; i<month; i++)
    {
        a[i] = input.nextInt();
        sum = sum+a[i];
    }
      System.out.println("Total profit : "+sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked!! thanks for your time and input

Comment: sorry new to stackoverflow..upvoted you now..thanks for the help again

Answer (score 2):

As the input suggests, you can't create an array with a negative size. You're properly checking the inputted `month`, but you don't terminate the flow when you get a negative value. `return`ing or `exit`ing at that point should do the trick. E.g.:

```
if (month < 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    return; // Here
}
```

Comment: Eureka!! That was the issue, thanks for helping a novice like me!!